# Wallpaper wonked out after signing back in when locked out

Tags: greeter, nvidia, wallpaper

Locked laptop, signed back in. This is the result.

Any advice, known issues or suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't manage to resolve this, however I did band-aid the issue until I care enough to find a root cause.

My band-aid solution:
added fix-wallpaper.pl perl script to cerbere you can do this with the elementary-tweaks from Philp Scotts PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

[image: tweaks>cerbere]

or via dconf-Editor
org>Pantheon>desktop>cerbere

[image]

fix-wallpaper.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#Run the fix wallpaper script
my $cmd = "dbus-monitor --session \"type='signal',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties', member='PropertiesChanged'\"";

open (IN, "$cmd |");

while (<IN>) {
if (m/boolean true/) {
exec('/home/nathaniel/Documents/Scripts/fix-wallpaper.sh');
}
}
```

fix-wallpaper.sh:

```
#fix wallpaper after unlocking
set-wallpaper /home/nathaniel/Pictures/wallpaper-312939.jpg
```

Now if the screen locks and I unlock it, it simply re-sets the wallpaper and no longer looks like static demons invaded my wallpaper.

Comment: If anyone actually knows the cause / resolution to this issue please let me know. I'd rather not have scripts I don't need running in the background if I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading NVidia driver to latest ver. 375 resolved a similar issue for me. don't know if you're running nvidia card